# Selecting data from two different tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 tables.

Table TSTRSN

```
[P]Client 
[P]Year 
[P]Rule_Nbr
Type_Code
```

Table TSTOCK

```
[P]Client
[P]Year
TimeStamp
EndOfFiscalYear
```

( [P] means Primary Key)

The request is twofold:

1) List a count of all the Rule_Nbr within a given time (from TimeStamp).

...then User chooses a specific Rule_Nbr...

2) List all Client, Year, EndOfFiscalYear for that specific Rule_Nbr

So for Part 1) I have to take the Rule_Nbr, take the matching Client and Year - use that to search for the TimeStamp. If it falls within the right time, increment count by 1... and so on.

Then for Part 2) I could either have saved the data from part 1 (I don't know if this is feasible given the size of the tables) or redo the query 1) for just one Rule_Nbr.

Im very new to SQL/DB2... so how to go about doing this? My first thought was make an array, store TSTRSN.Client/Year/Rule_Nbr and then prune it by comparing it to TSTOCK.Client/Year/Timestamp but I wonder if theres a better way (Im not even sure if Arrays exist in DB2!)

Any tips?

Comment: In standard SQL, there is no concept of an array due to normalization. Data that could be considered as an array generally is placed in a "sub-"table which, as you have learned, is accessed via a JOIN. Note that JOINs may be expensive.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `JOIN` keyword.

http://www.gatebase.toucansurf.com/db2examples13.html

Comment: Very Helpful. Thanks!